# What is correct format for on duplicate key update sql query ? Looks like typo mistake or something missing

Tags: php, sql, question2answer

I need to make on duplicate key update query, looks there is something missing in my query.

This query works fine with # in values

```
$insertqry=qa_db_query_sub("INSERT INTO test_table (userid,title, price) VALUES (#,#,#)", $userid, $title, $price);
```

I need to add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

This query works fine with on duplicate update but I need to add # in values to make it SQL injection safe.

```
$insertqry = qa_db_query_sub("INSERT INTO test_table (userid,title,price) VALUES ('$userid','$title','$price') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  title='$title', price='$price'");
```

I am trying this with # in values and does not seem to work.

```
$insertqry = qa_db_query_sub("INSERT INTO test_table (userid,title,price) VALUES (#,#,#)",$userid, $title, $price); ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  title=#, price=#", $title, $price);
```

Here is a reference on update DB queries to match format.
https://github.com/q2a/question2answer/blob/dev/qa-include/db/post-update.php#L126

Comment: `$insertqry = qa_db_query_sub("INSERT INTO test_table (userid,title,price) VALUES (#,#,#) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  title=#, price=#",$userid, $title, $price, $title, $price);`

Comment: Nick ! I tried this query. I am getting this error - [14-Apr-2020 00:01:17 America/New_York] PHP Question2Answer MySQL query error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 - Query: INSERT INTO....    Looks like there is typo with "

Comment: I don't know how you're getting a `"` in the query, there aren't any in the code I wrote other than the ones which delimit the string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My bad. I did not notice that i needed to put $title and $price two times. Now it worked fine without error. Thank you :)

Comment: Nick ! Your answer is best as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case i guess userid is a primary key or unique key...
just try

```
$insertqry=qa_db_query_sub("REPLACE INTO test_table (userid,title, price) VALUES (#,#,#)", $userid, $title, $price);
```

replace will automatically delete first record and insert new if unique key or primary key already exists

EDIT:
if you still want to use ON DUPLICATE KEY
try..

```
$insertqry=qa_db_query_sub("INSERT INTO test_table (userid,title, price) VALUES (#,#,#) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userid= VALUES(userid), title= VALUES(title), price=VALUES(price)", $userid, $title, $price)
```

Comment: Hi Shubhama ! Thanks for your input ! Yes. userid is unique key. It does work but it has few issues. Reference - http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice

Comment: okay then if you want to use on duplicate key, follows the code.. in EDIT

Comment: Thank you Shubham for showing both ways. It works great. :)